How do you keep concentration while compiling time?
In my project after every change I need to re-compile it during 3-5 mins. I can't just sit, so I start to watch videos/memes. Usually I return to check status after 10+ minutes, but that is small issue. After memes my concentration goes down and I need to dive again in bug/feature context. During day I do this many times and it feels like torture on hard tasks.
Maybe somebody have solved this moment?

In these situations, I would read a physical book.  It is less addictive.  Each sentence/paragraph/page takes about the same amount of time, and it is easy to mark where you left off.  Studies show you learn more from physical books.  You can add notes, there are no updates/popup/monitoring/censoring/volume changes/advertisements/bugs/etc.  Maybe I'm just old.  :-)
